# UICollectionViewLayout subclass cast to subclass

Tags: swift

I am trying to cast the following, but keeps coming up with the error below.

I am trying to achieve the objective c version of the following , which works fine:

`LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and is written in objective C.

Objective C:

```
 LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout *layout = (LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
```

Swift:

```
let layout : LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout = (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as AnyObject) as! LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout
        layout.swipeToDeleteDelegate = self
```

> Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout'
>   (0x111edda00) to 'LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout' (0x11040e3c0).

Answer (score 2):

What I did when I came against this issue was:

In **viewDidLoad()**

Code below needs to be added to replace the default layout object with our new custom flow layout object:

```
let carouselLayout = CarouselCollectionViewLayout()
self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(carouselLayout, animated: true)
```

Setting up the collection view:

```
let layout = self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! CarouselCollectionViewLayout
```

*ps: **CarouselCollectionViewLayout** is a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout*

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would just do:

`let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout`

Are you sure when you initialized the collection view you first created a `LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout` instance and set it as the `collectionViewLayout` argument in the `UICollectionView.init(frame:collectionViewLayout:)` method?

Comment: Hi there, what do you mean about the second part to your answer?

Comment: When you create a collection view you have to set the class responsible for layout, and it has to be a `LSSwipeToDeleteCollectionViewLayout` or you'll get the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class, which is probably why your typecast is failing.  You'll set the layout class either in your nib or directly in code as an argument to the `UICollectionView` initializer, depending on how you're creating the collection view.